# css footer not display at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

i am using this css for my footer:

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background:#666666;
    clear:both;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.footer-container {
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but i cannot get the footer to display at the bottom of the page

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2pvC/

Comment: Does it have a fixed height?

Comment: does what have a fixed height?

Comment: There is nothing in your formatting that would make it do that, so why’d you expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either position the footer **absolutely** to stay at the end of the page, or make it sticky by using `position: fixed`.

Here's an updated JSFiddle that represents the first option: http://jsfiddle.net/z2pvC/2/

Relevant footer CSS:

```
.footer {
width:100%;
background:#666666;
clear:both;
color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is called a sticky footer. Consult these resources to solve your problem:

<kbd>[Fixed your jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2pvC/4/)</kbd>

```
.
```

[CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) **Preferred*

[Ryan Fait's explanation](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

[Chris Coyer's solution](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

---

*Fixed your jsFiddle using the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) solution.*